# SQL union two complex query

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are 4 tables,

`posts(id`

`post_share(shared_by, post_id`

`friendship(friend_one, friend_two, status)`

`add_viewer(id`

By using above 4 tables I need to get posts to render in the user's news feed. Currently I only use the first query to do that which means I do not add shared post by user's friends to his/her news feed. Now I need to show the shared post, too just like in facebook.

For that I created new query ( 2nd one ). Now I want to connect both of them together and result only one table or **I would like to know if there's a better way to handle this**

By assuming currently logged in user_id is 22,

```
SELECT concat(a.fname, ' ', a.lname) as name, a.id as user_id , p.id as post_id, p.content, p.media FROM posts p
INNER JOIN add_viewers a
ON p.user_id = a.id
WHERE p.user_id in (
  SELECT a.id FROM friendships f
  INNER JOIN add_viewers a
  ON f.friend_one = a.id OR f.friend_two = a.id
  WHERE friend_one=22 OR friend_two=22 AND f.status='confirmed'
  GROUP BY a.id
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

in 2nd query, `s.shared_by` means the person who share the post and `p.user_id` means the person who created the post.

```
SELECT concat(a.fname, ' ', a.lname) as name, a.id as user_id , p.id as post_id, p.content, p.media FROM post_shares s
INNER JOIN posts p
ON p.id = s.post_id
INNER JOIN add_viewers a
ON p.user_id = a.id
WHERE s.shared_by in (
          SELECT a.id FROM friendships f
          INNER JOIN add_viewers a
          ON f.friend_one = a.id OR f.friend_two = a.id
          WHERE friend_one=22 OR friend_two=22 AND f.status='confirmed'
          GROUP BY a.id
)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  With t as
  (SELECT a.id as aid FROM friendships f
          INNER JOIN add_viewers a
          ON f.friend_one = a.id OR 
          f.friend_two = a.id
          WHERE friend_one=22 OR 
          friend_two=22 AND 
           f.status='confirmed'
          GROUP BY a.id) 

SELECT concat(a.fname, ' ', a.lname) as name, a.id as user_id , p.id as post_id, p.content, p.media FROM
  post_shares s
INNER JOIN posts p
ON p.id = s.post_id
INNER JOIN t
ON p.user_id = t.aid
OR s.shared_by = t.aid 

ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for the answer but I'm getting this error. `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"
LINE 16: ON p.user_id = t.id`

Comment: Now I don't see any errors but  I only get empty table. It should output 3 rows. The first query in the question output 2 rows and 2nd query output 1 row. For some reason it doesn't show any rows with this query.

Comment: But I got the idea. First we get the friends and we use it later right ?

Comment: I guess instead of where replace it with or should work then